# What is the purpose of specifying a clear color in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, buffer, libgdx

I'm working my way through the LibGDX framework, which provides a wrapper to make opengl calls.  I regularly come across the following pair of functions:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glClearColor.xhtml)(from OpenGL) explains that glClearColor allows you to:

*Specify the red, green, blue, and alpha values used when the color buffers are cleared.*

What is the purpose of selecting a specific clear color here, when it is then immediately overwritten by whatever gets rendered?  Should you choose a color that matches your scene?  Is it used to set the background for the scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do actually overwrite every pixel in every frame you render, you don't need to clear the color buffer *at all* (but usually, you still have to clear the depth buffer).

However, there are lots of use cases where a cleared buffer is required, and being able to select the background color is a useful feature there.

Comment: So is it purely for the purposes of setting the background color in those cases when it would show through?

Comment: @Sam: Well. basically, yes. "Clearing" in this context means filling with some predefined values - you might have a use for such an operation, or you don't. For a general API like OpenGL, it is a feature which should be present.

Comment: Try not to think of it in terms of colours. The colour buffer is simply an array of floats and you're gonna wanna be able to wipe these to a known value.